# What happened to Alexander Alekhine's family?

Tags: history, famous-players, alekhine

Alexander Alekhine, the former World Chess Champion, came from a notable family in Russia. His father, Alexander Ivanovich, was apparently Privy Councilor to the Duma and a Marshal of the Nobility. Alekhine himself was imprisoned during the Revolution and narrowly avoided being executed. His brother [Alexei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexei_Alekhine), apparently survived as well, going on to be chess player and editor under the Soviets. What about the rest of his family? Did they survive the Revolution?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Italian Wikipedia his father, Aleksandr Ivanovič Alechin, died in 1917, (so *probably* because of the revolution) and his mother, Anes'ja Ivanovna Alechina, died in 1915 in a clinic for mental illness. Alehkine's life during the revolution is not well known. Kotov's Alekhine biography should be a valuable source.